# Hci_write_local_name parameters explanation

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to know the details about the third parameter of the hci_write_local_name function. The first one is thesocket descriptor. Second the local name. And third one is a number which i thought the length of the second parameter. But if i use strlen of the second parameter the function fails. In hciconfig.c the value of third parameter for the same function is 2000. I tested with 100 as value. That worked. Can anybody say what exactly the third parameter implies?

Comment: I believe the 3rd argument is a timeout value. Although this command isn't part of the published API of BlueZ. The published APIs are at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

Comment: Okay... Timeout make sense... The prototype has "int to"... to must be timeout.... Another clarification.. Hope my understanding is ryt... The timeout value is  for setting the specific name for the adaptor within the specified time else returns error...

Comment: If you follow the code all the way it appears the timeout value is used for https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html

Answer (score 3):

As ukBaz mentioned, the third parameter is the timeout as can be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/Vudentz/BlueZ/blob/master/lib/hci.c#L1596):-

```
int hci_write_local_name(int dd, const char *name, int to)
{
    change_local_name_cp cp;
    struct hci_request rq;

    memset(&cp, 0, sizeof(cp));
    strncpy((char *) cp.name, name, sizeof(cp.name) - 1);

    memset(&rq, 0, sizeof(rq));
    rq.ogf    = OGF_HOST_CTL;
    rq.ocf    = OCF_CHANGE_LOCAL_NAME;
    rq.cparam = &cp;
    rq.clen   = CHANGE_LOCAL_NAME_CP_SIZE;

    if (hci_send_req(dd, &rq, to) < 0)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Most of BlueZ's HCI functions require a timeout parameter as the underlying **hci_send_req()** requires that.

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/Vudentz/BlueZ/blob/master/lib/hci.c#L1112) and the rest of the file.